# Iterate over a JSON Array in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to loop over a JSON Array which comes from the server. It looks exactly like this:

```
[{"username":"betontester"},{"username":"kuesst"},{"username":"master_pat"},{"username":"olli"},{"username":"test15"},{"username":"test20140216"},{"username":"test789"},{"username":"tester100"},{"username":"tobi"}]
```

I found some advices here, but none of them seem to work for me.. Is there any easy way to get all these values?

Comment: What did you try, and why didn't it work?

Comment: jquery.each on the array should work

Comment: can you explain jQuery each? I tried most of the thins stated here. Only thing i can get is 'Undefined', not the value which i need for

Comment: Where is the JSON data coming from? Has it been parsed? You really do need to show what you've tried.

Comment: yes it has been parsed and the response from the server is 1:1 to the pased example in my question. The response goes directly in the 'data' object which i am trying to iterate over

Comment: @TobiasKuess: I don't know if you really want an answer or not, but if you do, you need to show more info. Could be that the data is double encoded on the server, so when it's parsed on the client, it's still not the full structure you need. We could sit around all day and guess at what the problem may be, or you could provide something more than just a line of JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var arr = [{"username":"betontester"},{"username":"kuesst"},{"username":"master_pat"},{"username":"olli"},{"username":"test15"},{"username":"test20140216"},{"username":"test789"},{"username":"tester100"},{"username":"tobi"}];

    for(var i = 0; l = arr.length; i< l; i+=1)
    {
    console.log(arr[i].username); // log username
    }
```

another option:

```
arr.forEach(function(i) {
    console.log(i.username)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{"username":"betontester"},{"username":"kuesst"},{"username":"master_pat"},{"username":"olli"},{"username":"test15"},{"username":"test20140216"},{"username":"test789"},{"username":"tester100"},{"username":"tobi"}],
    usernames = [];

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    usernames.push(data[i].username);
}
```

Comment: is giving me a array full of 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var o = [{"username":"betontester"},{"username":"kuesst"},{"username":"master_pat"},{"username":"olli"},{"username":"test15"},{"username":"test20140216"},{"username":"test789"},{"username":"tester100"},{"username":"tobi"}];
for(var i = 0; i < o.length ; i++) 
    for(var j in o[i]) 
        alert(j + ": " + o[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need IE<9 compatibility, you can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var arr = [{"username":"betontester"},{"username":"kuesst"},{"username":"master_pat"},{"username":"olli"},{"username":"test15"},{"username":"test20140216"},{"username":"test789"},{"username":"tester100"},{"username":"tobi"}],
    usernames = arr.map(function(item) {
        return item.username;
    });
```